# Hypothesis Test for Difference Between Mean Within-Subject Variation

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have taken multiple measurements from individuals in three different groups. I want to test the hypothesis that within-subject measurements are more variable in specific groups compared to other groups.

My intuition is to do the following: calculate either the variance or standard deviation for each individual and conduct a one-way independent anova between the three groups. Is this valid?

Many thanks.

Comment: You mean a null hypothesis of $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma_3^2$? That’s not what ANOVA tests. Despite its name, ANOVA tests for differences in means, not variances.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am aware that ANOVA tests for differences in means. My idea was to use ANOVA to test for group differences in mean variance (G1: Var(subject1) Var(subject2) Var(subject3), G2: Var(subject4) Var(subject5) etc.). Does that make sense?